# TicTacToe game stuck in a while loop

Tags: python

I have the following code for a basic TicTacToe game. When playing the code does not break out of the while loop even when the winner is True and the length of used numbers is less than 9. I tried debugging it with breakpoints and the debugger indicates the breakpoint is hit, but the while loop persists.

```
def TicTacToe():
    #options available 
    nums = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    used = []
    
    #winner winner chicken dinner combinations
    
    
    #board 
    def board():
        print(f" {nums[0]}  |  {nums[1]}  |  {nums[2]}  ")
        print("----|-----|----")
        print(f" {nums[3]}  |  {nums[4]}  |  {nums[5]}  ")
        print("----|-----|----")
        print(f" {nums[6]}  |  {nums[7]}  |  {nums[8]}  ")
    
    # def progress(): 
        
    
        # return wwcd
    
    def round(player = "X"):
        print(used)
        winner = False
        
        while len(used) < 9 and winner == False:
            print(len(used))
            
            if player == "X":
                
                board()
                selected = int(input("Select number on the board to place X: "))
                if selected in nums and selected not in used:
                    used.append(selected)
                    nums[selected] = "X"
                    
                    
                    
                       
                    if (nums[0] == "X" and nums[1] == "X" and nums[2] == "X") or (nums[3] == "X" and nums[4] =="X" and nums[5] =="X") or (nums[6] == "X" and nums[7] =="X" and nums[8] =="X") or (nums[0] == "X" and nums[4] =="X" and nums[8] =="X") or (nums[6] == "X" and nums[4] =="X" and nums[2] =="X") or (nums[0] == "X" and nums[3] =="X" and nums[6] =="X") or (nums[1] == "X" and nums[4] =="X" and nums[7] =="X") or (nums[2] == "X" and nums[5] =="X" and nums[8] =="X"): 
                            board()
                            print("Congradulations X, you win!")
                            winner = True
                            break
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            
                    else:
                        print('O turn now')
                        round("O")
            elif player == "O":
                board()
                selected = int(input("Select number on the board to place O: "))
                if selected in nums and selected not in used:
                    used.append(selected)
                    nums[selected] = "O"
                    
                    
                        
                    if (nums[0] == "O" and nums[1] == "O" and nums[2] == "O") or (nums[3] == "O" and nums[4] =="O" and nums[5] =="O") or (nums[6] == "O" and nums[7] =="O" and nums[8] =="O") or (nums[0] == "O" and nums[4] =="O" and nums[8] =="O") or (nums[6] == "O" and nums[4] =="O" and nums[2] =="O") or (nums[0] == "O" and nums[3] =="O" and nums[6] =="O") or (nums[1] == "O" and nums[4] =="O" and nums[7] =="O") or (nums[2] == "O" and nums[5] =="O" and nums[8] =="O"): 
                            board()
                            print("Congradulations O, you win!")
                            winner = True
                            print('Hit, Winner found')
                            
                            
                            
                            
                    else:
                        round()
                        
                

                
            
    round()
    

TicTacToe()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a logical problem.

The `break` is working well after assigning `True` to winner variable. The problem is that you call the `round()` function again, so the winner became False again. To avoid this unwanted calling `round()` function at the end, you need some re-structure your code.

You declared variables such as `nums` and `used` at the beginning of `TicTacToc` function, but declared `winner` inside the function `round()`. It would be better to declare `winner` outside of the function `round()` so that `winner` keep assigned value.

However, if you declare `winner` outside of the function `round()`, it will throw an error because, unlike `nums` and `used` (`list` type), `winner` is not a list so it cannot be refer in `round` function. (To understand why, you may want to google [`call by reference and call by value`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value/430958#430958)). To resolve this issue, you can use `global` keyword inside `round` function, indicating that we will use the `winner` variable in the `round` function. Then, your code will work.

However, I highly recommend re-construct your code to avoid using `global` keyword because it sometime makes code confusing. It would be nice not using nested function.

Other minor problems are...

- Use different name of function for `round`, because it is pre-defined built-in keyword in Python.
- Use `winner is False` instead of `winner == False`. (PEP 8: E712 comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:')

Follwing is a code I fixed using `global`, so that it works. However, make sure that you need to re-construct the code without `global` and unnecessary nested functions.

```py
def TicTacToe():
    # options available
    nums = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    used = []
    winner = False

    # winner winner chicken dinner combinations

    # board
    def board():
        print(f" {nums[0]}  |  {nums[1]}  |  {nums[2]}  ")
        print("----|-----|----")
        print(f" {nums[3]}  |  {nums[4]}  |  {nums[5]}  ")
        print("----|-----|----")
        print(f" {nums[6]}  |  {nums[7]}  |  {nums[8]}  ")

    # def progress():

    # return wwcd
    def round(player="X"):
        print(used)
        global winner # meaning that you will use the winner declared outside.
        winner = False
        while (len(used) < 9) and (winner is False):
            print(len(used), winner)

            if player == "X":
                board()
                selected = int(input("Select number on the board to place X: "))
                if selected in nums and selected not in used:
                    used.append(selected)
                    nums[selected] = "X"

                    if (nums[0] == "X" and nums[1] == "X" and nums[2] == "X") or (
                            nums[3] == "X" and nums[4] == "X" and nums[5] == "X") or (
                            nums[6] == "X" and nums[7] == "X" and nums[8] == "X") or (
                            nums[0] == "X" and nums[4] == "X" and nums[8] == "X") or (
                            nums[6] == "X" and nums[4] == "X" and nums[2] == "X") or (
                            nums[0] == "X" and nums[3] == "X" and nums[6] == "X") or (
                            nums[1] == "X" and nums[4] == "X" and nums[7] == "X") or (
                            nums[2] == "X" and nums[5] == "X" and nums[8] == "X"):
                        board()
                        print("Congradulations X, you win!")
                        winner = True
                        break
                    else:
                        print('O turn now')
                        round("O")
            elif player == "O":
                board()
                selected = int(input("Select number on the board to place O: "))
                if selected in nums and selected not in used:
                    used.append(selected)
                    nums[selected] = "O"

                    if (nums[0] == "O" and nums[1] == "O" and nums[2] == "O") or (
                            nums[3] == "O" and nums[4] == "O" and nums[5] == "O") or (
                            nums[6] == "O" and nums[7] == "O" and nums[8] == "O") or (
                            nums[0] == "O" and nums[4] == "O" and nums[8] == "O") or (
                            nums[6] == "O" and nums[4] == "O" and nums[2] == "O") or (
                            nums[0] == "O" and nums[3] == "O" and nums[6] == "O") or (
                            nums[1] == "O" and nums[4] == "O" and nums[7] == "O") or (
                            nums[2] == "O" and nums[5] == "O" and nums[8] == "O"):
                        board()
                        print("Congradulations O, you win!")
                        winner = True
                    else:
                        round()

    round()  # This call the round function althouth winner is already True.

TicTacToe()
```

Comment: It worked, I will definitely look to restructure the code to avoid recursions. I was on a time crunch when I wrote the code.

Comment: @Gibbs We improve our skill like this. This code is great and I even enjoyed playing it along :) Hope you my answer help you improve your code and skills.